# How to encode Hashtable as Json?

Tags: java, json, encode

Is there any library to encode `Hashtable<String,String>` as Json? I've read about swift for Java, but I'm not sure that it fits.

Comment: There are dozens. Use google.

Comment: or simply use json library and create object like this. 
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(table);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(yourHashMap);
```

See the [documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).